# makefile with variable target

Tags: c, makefile

I'm attempting to define a Makefile that will take in a filename (eg. foo) as a variable from the command line, and then compile & link using gcc.
So if I type   **make foo**   it will compile **foo.c**  ,link up **foo.o** to the required libraries, and clean up the .o file. Here's my code so far, does anyone have any suggestions for where I'm going wrong?

```
@: $@.o
        @echo target is $@
        gcc $@.o -v -lmar -lbar -DDEBUG -o $@
        rm $@.o

$@.o: $@.c
        gcc -c -v $@.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make already uses the arguments as the target list.  And it already has [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) that do what you want.  You should be able to get away with something like this as your makefile:

```
LDLIBS=-lmar -lbar
LDFLAGS=-v
CFLAGS=-v
```